# Static transparent navbar over header image

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

**Situation**

I successfully created a transparent navbar which is overlayed on top of header image which has an SVG curve assigned to it.

I've been able to create the transparent navbar by amending some of the classes associated with the navbar such as removing `bg-light` for instance.

I've been able to overlay the navbar on top of the header image but applying the class of `fixed-top`.

**Issue**

While using `fixed-top` means the navbar appears above the header image, it also means that the when the user scrolls down, the navbar follows like a frozen row in Excel and obscures other text on the page. Instead, I want the transparent navbar to remain static and always appear at the top of the page. I'd like to know what further changes I need to make to achieve this.

**CODEPEN**
https://codepen.io/lowdowner/pen/gOdGVzx

```css
/* WAVE CSS */

.svg-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% * 45 / 1440);
}


/* PAGE SET UP */

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 650px;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518837695005-2083093ee35b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=53b711edbf0f887b5de376f91052d8f8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#title {
  font-family: 'Knewave', cursive;
  font-size: 8rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 16px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin-top: 1.25em;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h2,
a {
  color: #3086B9;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Wave Start -->
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <h1 id="title">Waves</h1>

  <div class="svg-container">
    <svg id="wave" viewBox="0 0 1440 45" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M0 39C0 39 291.625 0.0315932 479.5 0C667.764 -0.0316586 771.789 34.5337 960 39C1147.5 43.4495 1440 23 1440 23V45H0V39Z" fill="white"/>
            </svg>
  </div>


</header>
<!-- Wave End -->

<h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>
<h2>LOREUM IPSUM</h2>
<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>
```

Comment: it is unclear to me what is your issue, appart from the fact the bar is transparent , so the content is not well seen. But it sticks allright at the top . are you just missing a background?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As explained, I want a transparent navbar that is positioned on top of the header image yet remains static. I do not wnat the navbar to follow the user when scrolling down the page.

Comment: it is already on position:fixed at top (position:static mean following the flow by the way) You may also use position:sticky . But you example already works fine. What is it that i miss in your question ?

Comment: *While using fixed-top means the navbar appears above the header image, it also means that the when the user scrolls down, the navbar follows like a frozen row in Excel and obscures other text on the page. Instead, I want the transparent navbar to remain static and always appear at the top of the page.*  **on each side of the word instead, it is the same, with different words. can you rephrase ?**

Comment: On reflection I understand why my wording was confusing however I have now accepted and answer. Thank you for your input.

Comment: perfect for you, position in your code got me confused on the meaning too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually want fixed. You want absolute. But since the `fixed-top` class provides some things you *do* want, let's just override position with `position-absolute`.

Protip: Don't use alpha versions for production sites. They're even more risky than beta versions. The [official CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) doesn't provide either. Use stable versions.

```css
/* WAVE CSS */

.svg-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% * 45 / 1440);
}


/* PAGE SET UP */

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 650px;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518837695005-2083093ee35b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=53b711edbf0f887b5de376f91052d8f8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#title {
  font-family: 'Knewave', cursive;
  font-size: 8rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 16px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin-top: 1.25em;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h2,
a {
  color: #3086B9;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top position-absolute">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <h1 id="title">Waves</h1>

  <div class="svg-container">
    <svg id="wave" viewBox="0 0 1440 45" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M0 39C0 39 291.625 0.0315932 479.5 0C667.764 -0.0316586 771.789 34.5337 960 39C1147.5 43.4495 1440 23 1440 23V45H0V39Z" fill="white"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</header>

<h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>
<h2>LOREUM IPSUM</h2>
<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>

<p>LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Don't use alpha versions for production sites...'?

Comment: You've loaded an alpha version of Bootstrap. Look at the URL.